# Update between 2 tables with a subquery for the 2nd highest date row

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update all values of a column in a table 1 using a value from table 2 that has a corresponding id. The tricky part is that the value I need to pull from table 2 needs to be the 2nd highest date row, which I can use a date column for the 2nd highest date in the table.

This is what I have tried, but this is not an efficient query. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of going about this to achieve my goal.

```
UPDATE table1 tb1
SET newVal = (SELECT DISTINCT val
           FROM tb2
           WHERE tb1.id = tb2.id
           AND date = 
                  (SELECT MAX(date)
                   FROM tb2
                   WHERE tb1.id = tb2.id
                   AND date <
                          (SELECT MAX(date)
                           FROM tb2
                           WHERE tb1.id = tb2.id))),
update_time = SYSDATE
WHERE newVal IS NULL
AND EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT val
           FROM tb2
           WHERE tb1.id = tb2.id
           AND date = 
                  (SELECT MAX(date)
                   FROM tb2
                   WHERE tb1.id = tb2.id
                   AND date <
                          (SELECT MAX(date)
                           FROM tb2
                           WHERE tb1.id = tb2.id)));
```

I may be attempting something that is not possible in a single query but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNumber` and `RowNumber=2` in the where condition

Comment: @ErgestBasha That will get the second row and not necessarily (if there are ties for first) the second highest value. You want `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MERGE` statement and the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function:

```sql
MERGE INTO table1 t1
USING (
  SELECT id,
         val,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY val DESC) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           val,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE" DESC) AS rnk
    FROM   table2
  )
  WHERE  rnk = 2
) t2
ON (t1.id = t2.id AND t2.rn = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET newval = t2.val
  WHERE newval IS NULL;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (id, newval) AS
SELECT 1, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, NULL FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (id, "DATE", val) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01', 1.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-02', 1.2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-03', 1.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2022-01-01', 2.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2022-01-02', 2.2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2022-01-01', 3.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2022-01-01', 4.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2022-01-02', 4.2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, DATE '2022-01-01', 5.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, DATE '2022-01-01', 5.2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, DATE '2022-01-02', 5.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, DATE '2022-01-02', 5.4 FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `MERGE`, `table1` contains:

> | ID | NEWVAL |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1.2 |
> | 2 | 2.1 |
> | 3 | *null* |
> | 4 | 4 |
> | 5 | 5.2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c9c81843c6ae1bf7f71e2e07ea79c309)*